# Disable main menu

Tags: c++, visual-c++, menu, mfc, mdi

I have a menu that looks somewhat like the following,

[image]

When I open a particular dialog, I want to disable the whole menu. I realize that I can individually disable each menu item by using Update_Command_UIs, but that would mean adding event handlers for a 100 or more menu items. The menu is loaded initially with CMultiDocTemplate. Is there a way to do it by using the ID resource (IDR_MENU)?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Seems similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835209/how-can-i-disable-and-gray-the-top-level-menu-item-using-mfc

Comment: Dialogs are already modal.  So you can't get to the menu.  Hard to guess why you are asking this question.

Comment: @HansPassant: Unless they're modeless, of course. I'm not sure if that's the case here, and if so whether it's intentional.

Comment: Yes, the dialog is modeless, I need to access an OpenGL view in the application, so I've made it modeless. But since the dialog is dependent on other many dialogs in the menu, the menu has to be inaccessible.

Comment: The signature of `EnableMenuItem` suggests that only menu items with command IDs (not popups) can be disabled. However, `SetMenuItemInfo` may give you a workaround because you can reference items by position as well as by ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used ,

```
CMenu* pMenu = AfxGetMainWnd()->GetMenu();
if(pMenu != NULL)
{
    for(UINT i = 0; i < pMenu->GetMenuItemCount (); ++i)
        pMenu->EnableMenuItem(i, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_DISABLED);
}
```

as mentioned in http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?456136-Can-I-disable-menu-bar. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In your mainframe class, `m_wndMenuBar.EnableWindow(FALSE);`? The main menu items won't be grayed out, but they're not selectable.